# Missing constraints for progess view between different devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface

I use Xcode version 8. This is what I draw with the interface build:
[image]

A label and 2 progress view, bottom alligned.
I click on "Add missing constraints", then I run the simulator iPhone 6, and this is the result:
[image]

So far so good. Then I try simulating iPhone 5:
[image]

What I was expected was an automatic resize of the progress view width, but unfortunately it wasn't.
Here my constraints:
[image]

I see the fixed width, but removing it doesn't fix the issue.
How can I see the two progress bar resizing base on the devices, keeping the distance between each other and the label as well?

thanks

Comment: "Add missing constraints" can not guarantee what you are thinking in actual, IMHO you should manually mention the left, top, bottom margin with respect to your reference view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below step to set the layout of your Control. It will maintain the ratio between label and both progress bar

1. Add one view and one label in your cell. (see in image)
2. Add label constrains (Leading, top , width, Height).
3. Add view constrains (Leading, Top, Width, Trailing).
4. Add two progress bar in added view.
5. Select the both progress and define constrains like in below image. (Top, Leading, Trailing, Height, Equal Width)

[image]

Your Final constrains Looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add a leading constraint between second progress bar and first one :)